# Which Dependencies File Should I Use for my Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, dependencies, requirements, pipfile

I'm currently learning about **Docker**. I'm trying to use it in my python project (I'm using Django)

In my `Dockerfile`, I want my image to install the dependencies of my project into each new container.
I just created a requirements.txt file using the command tool 'pipreqs'

After looking at the content of this file, I realize that I have 2 others files related to the dependencies:

- `Pipfile`
- `Pipfile.lock`

I think they have been created and updated when I was using pipenv command.

My question is : Which one of these file should I use in my `Dockerfile`? `Pipfile`, `Pipfile.lock` or `requirements.txt`?

Comment: Requirements.txt is used to install any external dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Default choice is **requirements.txt with pinned versions**.

Versions can be pinned by `pip freeze > requirements.txt` or `pipenv lock -r > requirements.txt`.
You need Pipfile and Pipfile.lock if you going to use pipenv inside container. Then `pipenv install` will use your Pipfile.lock.